# Mock the result of cursor.execute() when using cx_Oracle for unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, cx-oracle

I am writing unit tests for a python script. I am connecting to oracle DB with cx_Oracle and then running a select query. The script does different things base don whether the query returns any rows or not. My code is something like:

```py
import cx_Oracle
.
.
.
def main():
.
.
.
  connection = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_string)
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute(query)
.
.
.
  headers = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
  d_file = open(data_file, "w")
        writer = csv.writer(d_file,delimiter='|',lineterminator="\n",quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        for row in cursor:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

I would like to patch the cursor.execute() method to return 0 rows.
I have tried the following by referring to a couple of answers here on SO. But I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'cx_Oracle'
```

My test is as follows:

```py
  @mock.patch('cx_Oracle')
  def test_invalid_data(self,mock_cx_Oracle):
    print("Starting test : Test with data file having size < 100000")
    mock_cursor = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_cursor.execute.return_value = []
    mock_cx_Oracle.connect.return_value.cursor.return_value.__enter__.return_value = mock_cursor

    with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
       dump_intexdb_n_load.main()
    self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 1)
```

How can I mock cursor.execute()?

Comment: You need to patch where the object is used, so if your tested module is called `dump_intexdb_n_load.py`, you should patch `dump_intexdb_n_load.cx_Oracle`. See more at https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch . Let me know if this helped.

Comment: @PeterK It worked. But now I'm getting an error "TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed". I have a `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError` in my main method. Could it be because of that?

Comment: I patched the method `dump_intexdb_n_load.cx_Oracle.connect` instad of the whole module and now it is working perfectly.

Comment: Great! I wrote it down as an answer so it's easier for people to see if they come across the question.

Comment: Also see [the doc on Subclassing Connections](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tracing.html#subclassconn). (This doc link is for python-oracledb, the new name for the latest cx_Oracle release.  The same applies to cx_Oracle itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to patch where the object is used, so if your tested module is called `dump_intexdb_n_load.py`, you should patch `dump_intexdb_n_load.cx_Oracle.connect`.

See more at https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch .